# How do I get my USB to show up in boot mode?

Tags: windows-7, boot, usb, bios

I'm running an HP Pro 3400 MT Series, Core i3, 8 GB RAM. It's a computer that I bought that came with pre-installed Windows 7 (This point, I'm not so sure about after seeing OS: Free DOS written on the side of the case. It could have been installed by the shop I bought it from - or I may have installed it and forgotten I did).

Now, because of an annoying virus infestation, I'm reinstalling software, except I'm trying my hand at Hackintosh.

I think my PC comes pretty close to examples of the Hackintosh hardware recommendations. So I downloaded El Capitan OS X on my Macbook Pro, and [using this video as my guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tZ1byvvV3Ok) I went ahead and downloaded software to set up a boot device with my 16 GB USB.

In the video, the guy advises you based on his chosen version of hardware. Because I'm using different hardware, the keys are different but the info is basically the same. I followed his advice on switching my boot mode from IDE to AHCI. It should be noted at this point that the BIOS that I'm at seems a lot simpler than most BIOS I've seen online, and on other computer. It just says "Hewlett Packard Utility" at the top. I don't know if that's normal, or if that's there because this is a computer with pre-installed Windows, and isn't allowing me to see under the hood. I say this because, after I followed all the steps, I tried restarting, and then accessing my USB from the Boot Menu, but I no longer saw my USB there. It was shown in the BIOS, but I couldn't see it in the Boot Menu. The USB was set for UEFI, and not Legacy, but I couldn't see it.

[Here's an image of the BIOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQCek.jpg)

I decided I'd re-do the USB configuration so it's set for Legacy, and not UEFI. This time I saw the USB, but as "1.00" which I'm not sure if that's actually the USB. I hit Enter, it started working, and then it stopped, and said Error, can't access Windows - something along those lines.

I looked online for why this is happening. Some people are suggesting that this is happening because the HP model is not allowing me to look under the hood because of copyright blablabla, it doesn't really matter. So I looked online for how to look under the hood and I couldn't really find anything. I also looked online for how to get the USB to show up in UEFI, and some people suggested enabling Legacy support in BIOS, and disabling Secure boot.

Problem is: I can't see either Legacy support, or Secure boot. Again the BIOS menu I'm getting is too rudimentary, it doesn't look like the full one.

So my question is: How do I get my USB to show up in boot mode, and/or how do I get to look under the hood - past this pre-installed HP Bios mumbo jumbo?

Comment: If only I could do that without accessing windows, that would be great, because the viruses that have taken over on this PC are innumerable and some of them have completely removed my power to install any software on there. I mean literally anything is steeped in error after error after error. It would take too much effort to untangle. I just want to wipe it clean and start over.

Comment: Post a picture of your BIOS screen.

Comment: I just realized on the side of the HP it says OS: Free DOS. So I may have been mistaken with it being pre-installed Windows, or not. I'm not so sure.

I'm also not sure of the difference - nowhere does it say on the PC any of those - it only says "HP Pro 3400 Series MT", PJ Mahoney. I think it's the latter. If a product no., or serial no. can help I can post that.

Comment: And if you don't have another computer to use, It's probably better to restore to factory configurations. All the computer manufactores have a hidden partition in the notebook with the system as it were when you bought it. You have to search for the specific configuration of keys to press in yours.

Comment: Lombas, I just posted a picture of the BIOS screen in the post

Comment: PJ, I just entered my product number into HP online, and what came out was HP Pro 3400 Microtower PC.

Comment: PJ, I'll try updating it, but I'm telling you no amount of antivirus software will solve my virus problem. You don't know how deteriorated my PC is. Idk if you've heard of Cryptowall 3.0, but that got on there, in addition to many other viruses that have slowly deteriorated system files in such a way that even Windows Installer can't work, and behind that there's missing system files, and corrupt system files. It's really a mess. Unlike anything I've seen before.

That being said, I also can't burn anything to CD cause I've got a Macbook Retina. But I guess I can try a USB.

Comment: So guys, just as an update, I tried reinstalling the BIOS driver from within Windows, and as expected it didn't work. A missing dll file showed up. I tried replacing it, it still wouldn't work. So I tried to format another USB to install the new BIOS from within DOS. So I booted up with the second USB and tried executing the file of the driver on DOS, but what I got was "This program cannot be run in DOS mode"

Lol my god this computers a pain in the ass

Answer (score 0):

This is not a definite answer, but may help:

1. Try updating the BIOS of you notebook.
2. Try booting Ubuntu, or another linux with the same USB flash drive doing the same stuff you did (UEFI, LEGACY, etc..). If it works, than it's probably a configuration issue with the Hackintosh.
3. Try getting into contact with HP support and asking them how to change advanced configurations on the BIOS (the under the hood stuff). If no joy, try searching for it for different models of HP notebook. Someone might have done it before.
4. You are probably not seeing the real BIOS config. Maybe there is a different key configuration to press to get into it.

Comment: Well, one thing worth noting, is that when I tried to adjust the Boot order of the USB in UEFI it didn't show and just went back to default settings. When I tried it with the USB configured in Legacy, and tried adjusting the position of the "1.00" to go above the Sata Hard drive - when I restarted the 1.00 was visible, but it was under the Sata Hard drive. So it seems that the adjustments of the boot order, and who knows maybe even all of the BIOS settings don't have an effect. But this is a nice plan. It just seems a little time consuming for me, but I'll use it if there's no other option.